# HTML/CSS - Moving LI Nav bar to the top right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to move an LI Nav bar to the top right of a page, however when I `position: absolute;` and `top: 0;` on my `<li>` I get my list which is also `display: inline;` all stacked on top of each other. They go to the part of the screen I want because I'm also `float: right;` but they won't stay in a line.

Any ideas?

HTML(html and doctype and link tags left out, they're there):

```
<div id="search">Google Search</div>
<div id="lucky">I'm feeling lucky</div>
<form>
<input id="search_box" type="text" name="">
</form>
<ul>
    <li class='nav'><a href="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=oz&passive=1209600&continue=https://plus.google.com/?gpsrc%3Dogpy0%26tab%3DwX">+You</a></li>
    <li class='nav'><a href="https://www.gmail.com/intl/en/mail/help/about.html">Gmail</a></li>
    <li class='nav'><a href="https://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi&ei=vSQnVJPAK8eIsQTRkYCQDg&ved=0CAQQqi4oAg">Images</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#search {
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 10;
font-weight: bold;
border: 1px solid black;
width: 7.2em;
white-space: nowrap;
padding-left: 4px;
padding-top: 3px;
padding-right: 4px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
margin: 240px 14px 100px 225px;
display: inline-block; }

#lucky {
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 10;
font-weight: bold;
padding-left: 4px;
padding-top: 3px;
padding-right: 4px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
border: 1px solid black;
display: inline-block; }


#search_box {
width: 600px;
position: absolute;
left: 65px;
top: 212px; }

ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0; }

.nav {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
padding: 20px;
position: absolute; }
```

Comment: Provide us all your html plz

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS, your question is too broad.

Comment: Try `display: inline-block`

Comment: @Csdtesting HTML and CSS added.

Comment: top right all the bottom nav you mean ?
right?

Comment: @Csdtesting Yeah I realize I should float it left, I was just messing with it, and I know I'll probably have to rearrange the list as I see that float right puts them backwards(unless there's a way to fix that too...)

Comment: @Csdtesting essentially I just want them to not stack on each other and stay in a line at the top... not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Try to remove position absolute so as not to stack.dow you want them top right as google?

Comment: @Csdtesting Yes, exactly. I'm rebuilding the website as a project and I can't figure out how to get the Nav bar to the top right without absolute positioning. How can I do that without that?

Comment: I answered just now with a working jsfiddle take a look

Answer (score 3):

The li's are stacked on top of each other because you are absolute positioning them to the same place. You want to make the ul absolute positioned instead. Include the code below in your css and for good measure you should also tell include something that it is positioned relative to.

```
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
}

.nav {
display: inline-block;
/* float: left;*/
padding: 20px;
/*position: absolute;*/ }

body{position: relative;}
```

Comment: Boom that was my issue, had to set the UL to absolute and the body positon. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/oe55maf0/2/

Added `#header` :

```
#header{
    float:right;
}
```

and removed `position:absolute;` from .nav class .Also added #content :

```
#content{
position:absolute;
}
```

to contain the form .
Now the structure is clear.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I had tried to fix it this way too, but the issue with that is it messed up all of the other placements for the buttons that I'm working on. Helpful but I think the above method is better and where I was missing. Thank you none the less.